# How to set merge and normalize multple dataframes for pd.merge_as_of

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, merge

I am trying to merge multiple dataframes using `pd.merge_asof`.

They all contain 2 columns with datetime as index column and a variable column with floating values. They are not balanced in their indexes and times so I have to normalize the values.

```
Date                    value1                                 
2021-10-22 19:22:25      23.5     
2021-10-22 19:22:40      23.4     
2021-10-22 19:22:55      23.5     
2021-10-22 19:30:12      23.6     
2021-10-22 19:30:42      23.5
```

```
Date                      value2                
2021-10-22 19:22:25        12
2021-10-22 19:22:40        12
2021-10-22 19:22:55        12
2021-10-22 19:30:12        16
2021-10-22 19:30:42        16
```

I can succesfully merge the dfs and normalize the values like this using

```
 merged = pd.merge_asof(data_frames[0],data_frames[1], left_index=True,right_index=True,direction='nearest')
```

```
Date                           value1  value2        
2021-10-22 19:22:25             23.5     12
2021-10-22 19:22:40             23.4     12
2021-10-22 19:22:55             23.5     12
2021-10-22 19:30:12             23.6     16
2021-10-22 19:30:42             23.5     16
```

Now what I want to do is to merge more than 2 dataframes. I tried doing this:

```
    merged = pd.merge_asof(data_frames[0],data_frames[1],data_frames[2],left_index=True,right_index=True,direction='nearest')
```

but I am getting the error

```
pandas.errors.MergeError: Can only pass argument "on" OR "left_index" and "right_index", not a combination of both.
```

I am not sure what it is indicating. I removed the one of the index arguments and it still said the same thing. Any way I can get what I need to do?

I want to be able to append dataframe3 which has value3 column to the right of value2 column.

Comment: Please post the line you are using to try to merge the third df, the error you posted means you are using keyword args `on` and `left_index` or `right_index` but `on` signifies: "Field name to join on. Must be found in both DataFrames." so pd is not allowing you to try to specify a join key and index for the same df. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html

Comment: @Jeremy edited to add line where error occurs

Comment: Checkout functools' [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, [merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html?highlight=merge_asof) can only accept two dataframes, the error is caused because in the third argument of the function it expects some other parameter.
As @Quang Hoang mentions you can use the `reduce` function to apply a two-parameter function cumulatively. The way in your case would be:

```
merged = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge_asof(left, right,left_index=True,right_index=True, direction='nearest'), data_frames)
```